# Boot mode set to Legacy support but Windows system information shows UEFI

Tags: windows-10, bios, uefi, lenovo-laptop

So I have a Lenovo g50-80 having a i3 4005u and I knew that my laptop has UEFI based Windows 10 as the drive is GPT when checked from disk management but to my surprise when I checked my bios options I got to know that Boot mode was set to Legacy Support. So why is my laptop even able to boot and is there anything wrong with this as I am able to use my laptop. Is there any risk.[attached the bios pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvVbR.jpg)
[attached the system information pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F683b.jpg)

Also I was trying to see if my bootable usb is working cause I am going to upgrade to a ssd with freshly installed windows 10 in without changing the legacy mode to UEFI as I didn't check bios till then
And saw weird horizontal lines[the lines were somewhat as in picture but with Lenovo logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hMOs.jpg) while the setup was booting but after that the installer interface came like normal. Are these lines normal. I am yet to install windows.

Comment: Legacy Support just means it WOULD boot if presented with an MBR disk. You should stop making system configuration changes to keep your system bootable.  "Are these lines normal?" - No

Comment: Confirmed here on  a Lenovo laptop. Also, turn Secure Boot ON (enable it) and the BIOS option for Legacy Boot will no longer be allowed (at least on my Lenovo system).

Comment: At this moment I am just playing it safe and backing up the data while it is working and as I am going to reinstall windows later on ssd I will change the bios settings before it. But I really do want to know how this laptop of mine is even booting at the moment XD